# Reset sort by color filter

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a column with numbers, and some are with colored background. When I use "Sort by color" from Filter drop-down menu, Excel sorts the column by selected color. I wonder how do I revert to previous sort state - how to reset "Sort by color" filter action?

PS. I don't want to use "Filter by color" instead, because with sort I get fast and easy continuous selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the column is not in any particular order prior to doing the 'sort by colours'.

If it is, you could just re-sort by whatever order the column was originally in.

Unfortunately, there is no 'unsort' or reset sort function in excel.

However if the column wasn't in any order, and you can't use Ctrl-Z to undo the sort, then there is a trick you can do prior to the colour sort.  Insert a column as an index column before the column where you have coloured cells, and number the values sequentially (insert 1, 2 and 3 and drag-fill the rest).

When you want the coloured column back in its original order, change the sort column to the index column and run the sort again.

Answer (score 0):

A very late answer, but this works for me :

Click on 'Sort and Filter', then 'Custom Sort'. In the new dialog box, choose the row where the sorting is applied, and click on 'delete' which is towards the top